# INNER JOIN entre dos tablas

Tags: mysql

estoy haciendo un INNER JOIN entre dos tablas para sacar información os pongo en situación.

En comentarios tengo los comentarios que hace la gente y comments_answer tengo mis respuestas a los comentarios los dos tienen un campo en común

**Comments**

```
ID
Nickname
Message
Post_id
Avatar
Fecha
```

**Comments_answers**

```
ID
Comment_id
Username
Message
```

el campo `comment_id de comments_answer` es el mismo campo que la `id` de `comments`

> Entonces yo lo que quiero es **sacar toda la información de las dos tablas con una consulta**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba este query y me dices si funciona

```
SELECT
c_a.*, com.*
FROM Comments_answers c_a
INNER JOIN Comments com
ON c_a.Comment_id = com.ID
```